# How can I except certain words from PEP8 naming convention?

Tags: pycharm

I want to except certain words that occur in variable names, function names, and parameter names from raising PEP8 violations.

For example, I use 'File' frequently such as:

```
def get_first_File(File_list):
  ...
File = get_first_File(Files)
```

And this would raise 5 warnings.
I don't want to suppress warnings altogether - only for certain words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to exclude specific words, unfortunately. You either have to disable the inspection globally (or for a specific scope). It is also possible to suppress the warning for a given function:

[image]

An alternative way is to install "Flake8 support" plugin and use `# noqa` comment to disable warnings. Feel free to create a feature request in PyCharm [bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY).